# How to achieve High Availability in Spring Cloud Data Flow

Tags: spring-cloud-dataflow

We are deploying `Spring` batch applications as Tasks in the Spring cloud Data `Flow(SCDF)`.
How to make `SCDF` "High Available"?

Kindly provide **guidance**

Answer (score 0):

As described in [SCDF's Gitter](https://gitter.im/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-dataflow?at=5dc96630ca778c1fbfe3504b) channel, you can scale SCDF (Boot App) To >1 in the targeted platforms like Cloud Foundry or Kubernetes. The platforms automatically create a load-balancer in front of the traffic.

When using SCDF in local-mode, however, though you can start multiple SCDF apps (`java -jar`), it is your responsibility to configure a load balancer to handle the incoming traffic.

Comment: Thanks for the response Sabby Anandan.. We have tasks scheduled in SCDF, where tasks(spring boot apps) are scheduled to run at configured times.. In this scenario, how will the LB help ? Won't all the instances of SCDF trigger the scheduled task?